# Floating point arithmetic in Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In kernel space, I have to do matrix multiplication whose elements are floating values(say 0.8666 etc).
Is it possible to do floating point arithmetic in Kernel space.
I am using 3.12 Kernel on ARM based board.

Comment: What degree of accuracy do you need, how many decimal places?

Comment: Up to 3 decimal places. say if the floating value is 0.8642 then I need till 4.

Comment: I would suggest scaling the value up and using ints then. It is possible to use float in kernel space but it has a LOT of issues associated with it. Since you don't need the accuracy I'd avoid it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will multiply all matrix elements with 100 or 1000 based on the accuracy. In my case I have to multiply around 3 matrices and only one matrix is having floating values, so at the end I will divide the elements of resultant matrix elements with 100 or 1000.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the kernel is always linked with FPU emulation so that it does work, but it's almost always wiser to use scaled integers.